# How can a Faraday cage absorb and reflect waves, yet antennas mostly absorb and can be used on signals?

Tags: rf, antenna, radio, emi-filtering, wave

I understand they are very different in structure but comparing a simple monopole to a Faraday cage, they both are constructed from metal.  Why is it the sides of the Faraday cage absorb the waves and retransmit, whereas for an antenna the waves are absorbed and cause a potential at the feedpoint?

From my understanding an antenna’s job is converting the freespace impedance to the feed-point impedance.  Is it something to do with, effectively, the Faraday cage does not have a matched ‘feedpoint’ hence the reflections and hence shielding, or am I completely off beat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *From my understanding an antenna’s job is converting the freespace
> impedance to the feed-point impedance, is it something to do with,
> effectively the faraday cage does not have a matched ‘feedpoint’ hence
> the reflections and hence shielding?*

An antenna works in both directions so, if the electrical feed-point is zero ohms (as it is with a faraday cage) then, the impedance it presents (in free-space) is also very low (much lower than the natural impedance of free-space). This means that incident power is reflected or transported around the faraday cage.

To take/remove/absorb incident RF power requires that the antenna presents the right free-space impedance. Anything less or more will not take/remove/absorb all the incident RF power.

Comment: Thankyou, so I suppose a correctly matched feed-point could turn the cage into an antenna? Also, i am confused when you say “ then, the impedance it presents (in free-space) is also very low (much lower than the natural impedance of free-space)” is this infering the present impedance at the antenna to free space changes depending on the feedpoint? Why is this?

Comment: It disrupts the localized impedance of free-space because it presents a lower impedance. An antenna is an impedance transformer (as you allude to in your question's 2nd paragraph) but, it works both ways as an impedance transformer. Of course, a faraday cage (a different type) can also be designed to wholly (near enough) absorb without reflection by being made from the right materials with the right sort of electrical resistance. It would inherently be the right impedance to fully absorb the radiated power hitting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a feedpoint to a Faraday cage, and turn it into an antenna. It's called a [slot antenna](https://www.electricity-magnetism.org/slot-antenna/#:%7E:text=Slot%20antennas%20are%20low%2Dprofile,%2DFi%2C%20and%20TV%20broadcasting.).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant to link to--it's not even a valid URL.